# Importing relative package modules in python doesn't work in the following format?

Tags: python

I have the following file setup:

```
package/
    __init__.py
    file.py
    file2.py
```

Where `file` has to import something from `file2`. To do this I was originally going to say `import .file2 as foo`, but that raises a syntax error. I also can't simply say `import file2` as you get a `No module named file2` error. How would you write this so that it doesn't raise an error?

Comment: As python is case sensitive are you **sure** that your `file2.py` is not called `File2.py` or some such?

Comment: 100% positive. It only raises that error when I try to use `import file2` in the package, which makes sense. What doesn't make sense is how you would write `import .file2 as foo` without raising a syntax error.

Comment: And you are absolutely sure you're inside the package folder when importing? Otherwise you'll have to `import package.file2`

Comment: Yes, I am importing `file2.py` from `file.py`.

Comment: The code and directory structure might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found out that the syntax I was looking for was:

In `file.py`...

`from . import file2 as foo`

Sorry if I didn't make that clear!

Answer (score 0):

In the file `__init__.py` have:

```
__all__ = ["file2", ]
```

This makes `file2` a member of the package.